# Kubernetes Disable Grafana

Tags: cpu-usage, kubernetes

We are using Kubernetes and successfully running our apps. However with our pods running and no traffic our minions are running with high CPU. Looking into the issue further:

- influxdb and heapster are running with high CPU, all of our containers are using 0% CPU, the box is at rest with a load of 8 on a dual core server...
- Looking at the individual containers doesn't seem to yield any answers, the logs are quiet

Grafana lets me view charts but the charts are broken and not really making a lot of sense. Is there any way to just remove this functionality all together from Kuberentes?

Kubernetes v1.0.6 deployed on Ubuntu Vivid on AWS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like to do so on a running cluster you can scale the rc:

> kubectl --namespace=kube-system scale rc monitoring-influxdb-grafana-v2 --replicas=0

Comment: My exact command was: `kubectl --namespace=kube-system scale rc monitoring-influx-grafana-v1 --replicas=0`

Answer (score 0):

Set `ENABLE_CLUSTER_MONITORING=false` env variable before creating the cluster. Relevant code [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/aws/config-default.sh#L90)